# 'set' does not work to get unique values in a column of lists in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I am not sure why 'set' does not get unique values in the following example:

```
df6 = pd.DataFrame({
                  'Name': ['Sara', 'John'],
                   'one': ['UK', 'UK'],
                   'two': ['IN', 'SA'],
                    'three': ['IN', 'IN'],
                     'four': ['IN', 'US']
                   })

df6
```

gives:

```
    Name    one     two    three    four
0   Sara    UK      IN     IN       IN
1   John    UK      SA     IN       US
```

I concatenated (one to four) columns in a list:

```
df6['Concat'] = df6[['one','two','three','four']].apply(lambda x: [', '.join(x[x.notnull()])], axis = 1)
```

gives:

```
    Name    one two three   four    Concat
0   Sara    UK  IN  IN  IN  [UK, IN, IN, IN]
1   John    UK  SA  IN  US  [UK, SA, IN, US]
```

Now I want to get the unique values only in the `Concat` column for each name:

I tried the following:

```
df6.Concat.apply(set)
```

but the result is the same as the original list!

```
0    {UK, IN, IN, IN}
1    {UK, SA, IN, US}
Name: Concat, dtype: object
```

Why 'set' does not work in such case?

I do not want the unique list ordered, but just to enhance my learning, how can I get the unique values ordered?

Comment: You applying set to a list containing one element a string. Note: df.loc[0,'concat'] returns ['UK, IN, IN, IN'], so set is going to return that single element a string 'UK, IN, IN, IN'.

Comment: @ScottBoston yes got it, it is a 'string' so when applying `df6.Concat.apply(lambda x: set(x.split(',')))` .. it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Concat` column consists of **lists of strings**. It is not a list. When you apply `set()` to that list, you get a set of one string. You should apply `set()` to the original data columns:

```
df6[['one','two','three','four']].apply(set, axis=1)
#0            {IN, UK}
#1    {SA, IN, UK, US}
```

The parameter `axis=1` instructs `apply()` to apply `set()` row-wise.

Comment: To be precise, his `Concat` column is a list containing exactly 1 string.

Comment: @TimRoberts Correct. Fixed it.